# Eclipse & Android SDK update really buggy as of 12/07/2012

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've just updated eclipse and the Android SDK now (12/07/2012 European) and it's really buggy, I have to constantly "clean project" just to get rid of simple errors like:

```
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
```

Even though there is obviously an ending.

Is anyone else having this problem and know of any fixes?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problems as well.  They appeared when I updated to the latest ADT plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: Exactly and they are extremely annoying, slowed down my development a great deal.

Comment: Getting very used to cutting blocks of code out and pasting them right back in once the error markers go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, this bug was fixed in ADT 20.0.1.

Comment: Use Eclipse's menu Help > Check for Updates to download and install the minor revisions to version 20. The Android SDK manager does not distinguish between minor revs.

Answer (score 2):

If you click on the error marker in the left margin, in the list of automatic corrections that pops up, there should be an option to clear all lint markers. Select it, and hit enter. It should take care of it if there isn't a real error on that line.

Comment: There is no option to do this and it's getting very annoying, I can't make a change without it throwing some random error that's completely  unrelated.

Comment: So when you click the error symbol in the left hand margin, [this](http://i93.photobucket.com/albums/l77/lanvarok/Untitled-2.png) doesn't pop up?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the *Type* Column of your problems view. If you see "Android Lint Problem" there, although this is a Java error message, then you ran into a bug of the current Android Lint.
You can either just hit the "Remove all warnings" button to clean the invalid errors (and you will get the valid errors again on the next build) or you can disable Android Lint completely, which I would not really recommend.

Answer (score 0):

It seems related to android linter. As suggested, if you bring up the quick fix interface when you have the cursor over the problem, both clicking the error marker on the left or by pressing cmd + 1 you should see an option that states "clear all lint markers"
Anyway it's an annoying bug that must be solved.